# Tkinter - Updating label and calling method on button press

Tags: tkinter

I have a callback method for a button that creates a label, adds it to the grid, *and then* calls a function I have imported from another file.  But when I press the button, I do not see the label until the function finishes executing. I tried adding a sleep call in between the label creation and function call, but I have read else where sleep() does not work in tkinter.  How do I get my label to appear on button press, and then perform the function call, not the other way around?

Comment: dont use sleep() or wait() in tkinter. Use after() instead. That being said please provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get what I wanted by calling Tk.update()